# Python:Bounding box coordinates of group instance (empty object)

Tags: python

I can see group bounding box so it covers all the group objects but how to get those coordinates ?

Comment: Don't get it - bounding box is (0,0,0,0,0,0 ...). I've thought it's a good idea to get the parent group and calculate the box, but the _empty of the group instance_ is not in the center of the group, so I have no idea how to calculate the differences between the _group_ and the shifted _instance_. What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: I want to create a plane (2d), the same size than group instance bounding box.

Comment: "I can see group bounding box so it covers all the group objects" - how do you do that? Does a single bounding box surround all the objects in the group?